# Which versions of the .NET Framework support the System.Threading namespace?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Which version of the .NET Framework introduced the System.Threading namespace? Is it possible to use this in a .NET Framework 3.0 application?

Edit: My application depends on the Thread class.

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace has been there since the first version - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) is the documentation for version 1.1.

Some of the versions following have added classes and functionality, so it really depends on what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it was present sice Version 1.1. Sure you can!

Answer (score 0):

.NET 1.1 introduced this namespace as seen in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.Threading` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) has been there since at least .NET 1.1, so you should be fine using it in a .NET 3.0 application.

Of course, that doesn't mean all of the classes defined *within* this namespace were there from the beginning, but you don't specify any particular class of interest in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Threading` namespace has been around since the 1.0 version of .Net was released.

However this probably isn't what you need to be concerned about.  Programs don't take dependencies on namespaces, they take dependencies on types within a namespace.  While the `System.Threading` namespace has been around since 1.0 many of the types within it didn't appear until later versions.

Could you tell us what type it is that you want to depend on?